# searching unicode string

Tags: java, string, unicode, encoding, comparison

I am working in a application that takes unicode string as a input. I successfully obtained the sets of words as a list. Now i need to search the input string in the given sets of string that are in the list. I tried to compare the given string with each string in the list but only gets the unrecognised characters as an output. I think the problem is with the unicode precessing. Is there any suitable way to do this?

Comment: Example code will greatly improve the chances of a useful answer.

Comment: And please edit your original question to add the example code. Don't post it in an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Java works with unicode (String is UTF-16 internally, but handles all Unicode, see the [API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode) for more information). If you have problems with "unrecognised characters", you may have read the input with the wrong encoding or stored in a wrong way.

No more specific help possible without any source code given, sorry.